# How to get the slide direction of pivot item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, pivot, gesture

I have a pivot control with pivot items on windows phone 8.1. I know how to get the current pivot item by the method SelectedIndex but I need to know on which pivot item I was before the current one.

I've heard about Gesture caching or ManipulationCompleted? I need to know which direction was used to slide on the current pivot item? Does somebody know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know the previous index, you can take advantage of *SelectionChanged* event. For example like this:

```cs
// somewhere in constructor
MyPivot.SelectionChanged += MyPivot_SelectionChanged;

int previousIndex;
private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    previousIndex = MyPivot.Items.IndexOf(e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault());
    Debug.WriteLine("Previous index: {0}", previousIndex);
}
```

If you have more items in your *Pivot* than two, then this method will also allow you to identify the direction of the swipe gesture.